# Changing the Sweave driver from the command line

Tags: r, latex, sweave

My current `Makefile` for weaving looks something like:

```
SUFFIXES: .tex .pdf .Rnw
MAIN = lecture
INCLUDES = chapter1.tex chapter2.tex ...

all: $(INCLUDES) $(MAIN).pdf

$(MAIN).pdf: $(INCLUDES) $(MAIN).tex

.Rnw.tex:
        R CMD Sweave $*.Rnw

.tex.pdf:
        pdflatex $*.tex


<snip>
```

Suppose I want to change the Sweave driver to use the [highlight](http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?category/R-package/highlight) package (say). What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do what we do for the Rcpp* packages. Here is RcppGSL:

```
RcppGSL.pdf: RcppGSL/RcppGSL.Rnw
    cp -f RcppGSL/RcppGSL.Rnw .
    $(RSCRIPT) --vanilla -e "require(highlight); \
                             driver <- HighlightWeaveLatex(boxes = TRUE); \
                             Sweave( 'RcppGSL.Rnw', driver = driver ); "
    $(RSCRIPT) -e "tools::texi2dvi( 'RcppGSL.tex', pdf = TRUE, clean = FALSE )"
    bibtex RcppGSL
    $(RSCRIPT) -e "tools::texi2dvi( 'RcppGSL.tex', pdf = TRUE, clean = TRUE )"
    cp RcppGSL/RcppGSL-fake.Rnw RcppGSL.Rnw
```

This keeps the actual source and a 'fake' variant in a subdirectory `inst/doc/RcppGSL/` 
to trick R into recreating the pdf only when we want it too---otherwise it sees an Rnw and pdf of the same basename and is happy.

A little more convoluted than the basic `Makefile` you started with, but currently still 
the only way to switch to [highlight](http://cran.r-project.org/package=highlight) that we know.

Comment: Many thanks. I just have to change `R CMD Sweave...` to `Rscript...` and everything will work. I don't use R to pdflatex, I just have an additional `Makefile` suffix command, this means (I think), I can avoid "fake" directories.